# Htaccess to block access to specific Mediawiki page?

Tags: .htaccess, mediawiki

In Mediawiki, I'm trying to find a way to block access to some of our template pages. I don't want some of our competition viewing our complex code and stealing it for their wikis (which is common in the fandom I'm from unfortunately). So I was trying to use htaccess to accomplish this by redirecting people to the main wiki page when they try to view a specific template page. However, nothing is happening. Here's what I used:

Redirect /wiki/index.php?title=Template:Box /wiki/index.php

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible, though, or if this is how htaccess is supposed to be used!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways of getting template content in MW, and MW has its own access control extensions, so I think that you are trying to cure a leaking sieve, but answering your Q directly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} \bTemplate:Box\b
RewriteRule  wiki/index.php  $0?             [L]
```

This will remove the query parameters if the URI is for `/wiki/index.php` and the query string contains **Template:Box**.

Comment: Thank you so much! What do you mean though with your first few sentences? People will still be able to get the template content if they want to or something?

Comment: Most wiki implementations allow SEO-style rewriting but one advantage of this rewrite rule is that it will pick up these internal rewrites.  I've just had fun myself configuring access control in Mwiki, so don't assume that you're 100% secure.  I am also an open minded guy, and I do find it a little ironic that you're worried about locking down proprietary templates in an FLOSS package.  WP itself probably has far better examples of templates than you will probably develop yourself.  How about a tick if I've answered your Q even we have a different PoV on open vs closed :-)

Answer (score 3):

In short words: **don't do that!**

Let me quote the relevant part of MediaWiki docs: [MediaWiki is not designed to be a CMS, or to protect sensitive data. To the contrary, it was designed to be as open as possible. Thus it does not inherently support full featured, air-tight protection of private content.](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Security_issues_with_authorization_extensions)

There's no way MediaWiki guarantees partial read permissions: either people are able to see every page, or none of them. Otherwise, there will be loopholes to read your precious data. For example, TerryE's trick with rewrite rules adds absolutely no security: among a hundred of other ways, one can simply change `Template:Box` into `Template_:_Box` and the latter will be normalised internally into the former. MW sometimes HTTP-redirects to normalised titles, but that is very easy to overcome.

Comment: I've just +1'ed your A because I agree with these sentiments.  However, I view our role as to give advice but also to answer direct Qs when asked clearly.  I am not sure that your example applies here as this kind of proprietary wiki would only make sense where a limited number of trusted accounts have edit access.

Comment: @TerryE: I've always thought that when the questions ask for something bad, we shouldn't explain how that bad thing can be accomplished. The particular question is made even more complex by the fact that the template to be hidden is used on other pages that people are supposed to be able to see. This increases drastically the number of possibilities to work around such protection.

Comment: Another problem with rewrites is that they kill the ability to edit the page legitimately. So the next question will be how to add exemptions via IP whitelisting (kicks you out when you travel) or HTTP auth.

Comment: The MediaWiki docs are overly cautious about authorization extensions in my opinion. In modern versions of MediaWiki, the userCan hook will take care of most (if not all) entry points before showing content to a user. At least some of the [authorization extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_specific_user_rights_extensions) should handle this user's use case.

Comment: @Christian: none of them will help because OP asks for template source to be impossible to view yet useable on publicly viewable pages - what userCan is supposed to return here? And even if you just need to make some pages unconditionally not readable by some groups - don't hide your really valuable secrets this way, seriously;)

Comment: @MaxSem Sure they will. OP could use [Extension:Lockdown](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown) for example to restrict access to pages and then not set $wgNonincludableNamespaces for the template namespace. This would protect the pages themselves but allow them to be transcluded.